# VBA to sort Dynamic data range by Last Column (specific rows)

Tags: excel, vba

Appreciate if someone could advise how do I SORT DYNAMIC DATA (being the filled last column can vary each month) BY LAST COLUMN FROM SPECIFIC ROW (specifically ROW 5).

I read that VBA to sort last column could use:

```vb
Sub SortLastColumn()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Columns(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column).Sort key1:=Columns(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column)
    End With
End Sub
```

But this return all my data starting from Row 1. I am not sure how i could have a work around.

Look forward to a favourable solution. Thank you!

Comment: Your current code sorts only the last column and not the complete data. Is that what you really want? And do you want to exclude the first 4 or 5 rows from the 'sort'? Please, do clarify.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008 for the reminder. yes I would need to sort the entire data by the last column. Is there a way? Appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: You should refresh/reload this page and see that you already have two answers.

Answer (score 1):

### `Sort`: `CurrentRegion` vs `UsedRange`

**Microsoft**

- [Range.Sort Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)
- [Range.CurrentRegion Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)
- [Worksheet.UsedRange Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange)

**A Thought**

- Although the code for the `CurrentRegion` version is a little more complicated and forces you to specify the address of the first cell of the data, I prefer it because it allows you to have other data in the worksheet, not just the 'table'.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortByLastColumnCR()
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const FirstSortRow As Long = 5
    
    ' Define Complete Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(FirstCellAddress).CurrentRegion
    ' Get rid of possible data to the left and above of first cell
    ' if First Cell Address is differenct than "A1".
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(FirstCellAddress, rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, _
                                                            rng.Columns.Count))
    
    ' Define Sort Range.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - FirstSortRow + 1) _
                 .Offset(FirstSortRow - 1)
    
    ' Sort.
    rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count), _
             Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub

Sub sortByLastColumnUR()
    
    Const FirstSortRow As Long = 5
    
    ' Define Complete Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    ' Define Sort Range.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - FirstSortRow + 1) _
                 .Offset(FirstSortRow - 1)
    
    ' Sort.
    rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count), _
             Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much VBasic2008, this works like magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the first 4 rows from your sort range.

So, walking through it, first define the range you want to sort.

```
Sub SortLastColumn()

    Dim sortRange As Range

    Set sortRange = Range( "A5", Cells( ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, _
                                        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count ) )
    ' Now do the sorting

    sortRange.Sort Key1:= Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)

End Sub
```